# Increasing Array Size dynamically

Tags: asp-classic

I have this array in ASP

```
CONST CARTPID = 0
CONST CARTPRICE = 1
CONST CARTPQUANTITY = 2
dim localCart(3,20)
```

I add items to this array dynamically like this

```
localCart(CARTPID,i) = productId
localCart(CARTPRICE,i) = productPrice
localCart(CARTPQUANTITY,i) = 1
```

The problem is, after 4 items, I can still add the items but UBound always return 3. Which causing my conditions failing.

I want to increase size of this array at run time so that UBOUND can return latest value.

Please let me know how can i do that. Here is my complete code

```
'Define constants
 CONST CARTPID = 0
 CONST CARTPRICE = 1
 CONST CARTPQUANTITY = 2

 'Get the shopping cart.
 if not isArray(session("cart")) then
dim localCart(3,20)
 else
localCart = session("cart")
 end if

 'Get product information
 productID = trim(request.QueryString("productid"))
 productPrice = trim(request.QueryString("price"))

 'Add item to the cart

 if productID <> "" then
foundIt = false
for i = 0 to ubound(localCart)
    if localCart(CARTPID,i) = productId then
        localCart(CARTPQUANTITY,i) = localCart(CARTPQUANTITY,i)+1
        foundIt = true
        exit for
    end if
next
if not foundIt then
    for i = 0 to 20

        if localCart(CARTPID,i) = "" then
                            ***ReDim Preserve localCart(UBound(localCart, 1) + 1,20)***
            localCart(CARTPID,i) = productId
            localCart(CARTPRICE,i) = productPrice
            localCart(CARTPQUANTITY,i) = 1
            exit for
        end if
    next
end if
 end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think redimentioning the array with the current UBound+1 after each addition of new item will make UBound gives you the latest value finally.

```
// New item addition code will go here
ReDim localCart(UBound(localCart, 1) + 1,20)
```

So it will update your array with the new size every time you will add the new item.

Comment: Thanks, this works but I can't preserve the values. As soon as I use ReDim Preserve, i get this error:                                 Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009' 

Subscript out of range 

/prices_test.asp, line 102

Answer (score 5):

If your adding the items dynamically in a loop you'll want to use the `Redim Preserve()` statement.  You'll want to use the `Preserve` part so you don't lose any of your existing data.

Otherwise if your using the array data and then redimming it for another set of data you can just the `Redim()` statement

Here is a good reference on using `Redim()` / `Redim Prevserve()` Statments: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/can-i-create-an-array-s-size-dynamically.html

Answer (score 1):

The first dimension is only 3 in length, while the second dimension is 20. If you want the UBound of the second dimension, do this:

```
UBound(localCart, 2)
```

Which returns 20. You should be able to combine this with ReDim Preserve.

Comment: thanks, how do i increase first dimension dynamically? please can you share Redim statetement?

Comment: AFAIK you can only resize the last dimension of an array. Do you need to add another attribute besides productid, price and qty?

Comment: no i don;t need any other attribute. Rows are limited to 4 in this case, i want to add rows dynamically not columns. please suggest.